# XSLT and numbers in attributes

Tags: templates, xslt, attributes, numbers

I have an xml-fragment like this:

```
<p rend="noIndent">eget <seg type="comStart" n="com123"/>kunde<seg type="comEnd" n="com123"/> der i Anledning af disse <seg type="comStart" n="com13"/>kunde<seg type="comEnd" n="com13"/> Smaadigte være at s</p>
```

I want to change the numbers in the n-attribut and make the numbers starts with 1. The values in the n-attribut shold be the same for each pair of comStat and comEnd in the type-attribute, ending up with this result:

```
<p rend="noIndent">eget <seg type="comStart" n="com1"/>havde<seg type="comEnd" n="com1"/> der i Anledning af disse <seg type="comStart" n="com2"/>kunde<seg type="comEnd" n="com2"/> Smaadigte være at s</p>
```

How do I match the corresponding n-attributs in xslt?

KSR

Answer (score 2):

If there are always pairs you can simply create the number using `xsl:number` for the `comStart` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[@type = ('comStart', 'comEnd')]/@n">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">n<xsl:number level="any" count="*[@type = 'comStart']"/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbm

respectively

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@type = 'comStart' or @type = 'comEnd']/@n">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">n<xsl:number level="any" count="*[@type = 'comStart']"/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for XSLT 1 (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiQZDbm/1).